# Show monthly archive of only one category (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress

On my blog's archive page if I click on a month, it takes me to a page showing me all the posts that I've created that month (obviously). Is there a way to filter that page so it only shows me posts from one of my categories?

**archive.php**

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

    <div class="rightColumn">
        <?php
                while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                    get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
                endwhile;
                    // Previous/next page navigation.
                    twentyfourteen_paging_nav();
                else :
                    get_template_part( 'content', 'none' );
                endif;
            ?>
    </div>

<?php
get_footer();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up finding a solution that worked for me:

```
function only_show_blog_posts( $query ) {
   // Only modify the main loop query
   // on the front end
   if ( $query->is_main_query() && ! is_admin() ) {
      // Only modify date-based archives
      if ( is_date() ) {
         // Only display posts from category ID 1
         $query->set( 'cat', '12' );
      }
   }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'only_show_blog_posts' );
```

Answer (score 1):

try using the `pre_get_posts` hook, something along the lines of:

```
function filter_by_category( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_archive() && $query->is_main_query() && basename( $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ) == 'archive.php' ) {
        $category_id = get_cat_ID( 'THE_CATEGORY_NAME' ); //change to the actual name of the category you are filtering with
        $query->set( 'cat', $category_id );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'filter_by_category' );
```

you can drop this code into your functions.php file

you can find more info about the `pre_get_posts` hook [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts)

Comment: The ony problem with this code its that does it site wide, and when I go to the pages for my other categories no posts show up. Is there a way to target ONLY the Archive.php page?

Comment: you can try adding `&& basename( $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ) == 'archive.php'` to the if statment

Comment: the if statement...I edited the answer to include it

Comment: I can't see what's happening server side on your site. I can only give you these pointers and it is up to you to try to implement them server side...try using `$GLOBALS['pagenow']` or `$pagenow` instead of `basename( $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] )` check. For $pagenow, you'll need to declare it as `global $pagenow;` before the if statement

Comment: I ended up finding a solution that worked for me, don't know if thats the best way to do it tho. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That simple hook helped me too. I modified the function a little to get the category Id from $_GET:

```
function only_show_blog_posts( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_main_query() && ! is_admin() ) {
      $catId = (int)$_GET['catId'];
      if ( is_date() && is_int($catId)) 
        $query->set( 'cat', $catId);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No filters or hooks necessary. Just pass the category you want to filter for in the URL.

With an ID
`https://myblog.com/2018/?cat=1234`

With a slug
`https://myblog.com/2018/?category_name=my-category-slug`